# embedded uclinux footprint on cortex M3

Tags: arm, cortex-m, uclinux

I am having trouble with this question, somebody (hopefully mistakenly) moved the previous question to Unix/Linux list which has zero uclinux tagged questions. This is more of a embedded linux question..

I have a question about the footprint of uClinux. I have looked around to find a breakdown of requirements, there is no nice info on the net. The modules under interest are:

Core kernel TCPIP stack Serial Driver DHCP WiFi Support (any of the stack from vendors is ok) I am looking for RAM/Flash breakdown. I don't need a filesystem however there is a chance that I need it due to the driver model of Linux.

Bonus question: - Porting drivers from Linux to uClinux. I know the memory architecture is different. Considering driver doesn't do anything special wrt memory, could I just recompile the driver and expect it to work under uClinux?

Comment: Does uclinux run on a Cortex at all?

Comment: Cortex-M, I mean, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the drivers work pretty well. This driver has been ported to uClinux on Blackfin and STM32. http://www.sagrad.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=130&Itemid=130

The are running a sale on the ICs,  Most of their modules that support WiFi and linux work with uClinux.